# how to clone a treeview c# and save it to recover later

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

i need to clone an entire treeview to implement Undo\Redo actions. i try in different ways but it appears that directly isn't possible. I mean copying the entire treeview, save that copy in a list. Then when the Undo action is requested decrement a specific counter of levels of undo and replace the actual treeview with the treeview that exist in the index positions of the list. if I do redo the same happens but lvls is incremented so i recover what come next. Every time that a modifications occurs in the treeview i need to save that copy and increment the lvl counter

Comment: This is an issue with the WinForms approach of tying the presentation to the data. Think of it a different way; modifying the underlying data and figuring out a way to propagate that to the UI.

Comment: nop, the organization of the treeview is what drive my application behavior, it's not in the other way, at least for this specific case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of cloning the treeview itself you could simply clone the TreeNodes (see [TreeNode.Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.clone%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)).  It seems like the important bit is the relationship between the nodes, so this would probably work for you (I say "probably" because I haven't actually done this myself, so I can't tell you if there are any caveats to be wary of).

Comment: thanks! it works, i couldn't find the Clone method with my simple exploration because i forgot to change the "var" keyword in the foreach loop to the corresponding TreeNode type, T_T. Now i'm thinking how can i save his expansion status because they are lost in the copy,recover, process

Answer (score 4):

I think you should consider going about this a different way.

You don't need to store the entire TreeView in order to keep track of undos and redos.  You only need to keep track of the changes:

- If you add a node, the undo is to remove it, so you only need a reference to that node.
- If you remove it, the undo is to add it, so you need a reference to the added node and the node it was added to.
- If you delete a whole branch, then you need to store the branch and the node it was deleted from.

And so forth.  I think you'll have better luck doing it this way than trying to store the entire tree.  And I've done it this way in applications where I've implemented undo/redo.

Comment: yea your right my idea is literally brute force, i'm going to think in what you suggest. The tree also brings the possibility to move and copy any subtree to any subtree, so using a composite of the tracked changes that you say could help me to define this actions. Also i'm interested in undo redo any expansion/collapse operation.

Comment: You might find my answer to this question helpful for more details on how to implement the undo/redo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058146/what-real-world-uses-of-the-stack-object-net-have-you-used/2058359#2058359

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (GoF):

- Put your actions logic into classes
  which implement common ICommand
  {Do(); Undo();} interface.
- On each user action you create object
  of command requested and initialize
  it with context parameters like new
  and old filename.
- Call Do(), put object into stack of
  completed commands.
- Each command is supplied with
  context, so by calling Undo() it can
  reverse changes.
- Consider moving files into temporary
  folder instead of removals.

Also, for a quick linear undo/redo, another option is the [Memento pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMemento.aspx) using zip of file as memento.

Answer (score 1):

This is my shot at it, no big objects being moved in memory:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace treeundoredo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static TreeNode GetNode(string id, TreeNodeCollection root)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in root)
                if (node.Text == id)
                    return node;
                else
                {
                    var subnode = GetNode(id, node.Nodes);
                    if (subnode != null)
                        return subnode;
                }

            return null;
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // list of (node, parent)
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> undo = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(), redo = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            Random rng = new Random();
            TreeView Tree = new TreeView() { Size = new Size(200, 250) };
            Tree.Nodes.Add("Root");
            Tree.NodeMouseClick += (s, e) => { undo.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(e.Node.Nodes.Add(rng.Next().ToString()).Text, e.Node.Text)); Tree.ExpandAll(); redo.Clear(); };

            Button Undo = new Button() { Text = "Undo", Left = 205 };
            Undo.Click += (s, e) => { if (undo.Count > 0) { var kvp = undo[undo.Count - 1]; GetNode(kvp.Key, Tree.Nodes).Remove(); redo.Add(kvp); undo.Remove(kvp); } };

            Button Redo = new Button() { Text = "Redo", Left = 205, Top = 50 };
            Redo.Click += (s, e) => { if (redo.Count > 0) { var kvp = redo[redo.Count - 1]; GetNode(kvp.Value, Tree.Nodes).Nodes.Add(kvp.Key); redo.Remove(kvp); undo.Add(kvp); Tree.ExpandAll(); } };

            Form frm = new Form();
            frm.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { Tree, Undo, Redo });
            Application.Run(frm);
        }

    }
}
```