# Generically comparing properties of objects, with a little recursion to boot

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, recursion

I have a couple of complex objects that I'd like to compare properties on.  The following code does a fine job, up until you get to a collection.   I'd like to recursively call the function with each member of the collection.  Can someone take a look and help me to determine the type of object in the collection so that I can call HasPropertyChanged again?

This pseudocode shows my intent

```
      if (p.GetType() == typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>))
       {
            foreach (var blah in //the list)
            {
                HasPropertyChanged<//TheType>(Type obj1, Type obj2, null);
            }
        }
```

Also, this part of the code bugs me.  If I don't call the tostring method, I'll get some funky results, like id 63633 not equaling 63633

```
    object val1 = Original.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(Original, null);
        object val2 = Modified.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(Modified, null);
        if (!IgnoreProperties.Contains(p.Name) && 
            val1 != null && val2 != null && 
            val1.ToString() != val2.ToString())
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Here it is in it's entirety.

```
private bool HasPropertyChanged<T>(T Original, T Modified, string[] IgnoreProperties)
    {
        if (Original == null || Modified == null)
            return false;
        if (IgnoreProperties == null)
            IgnoreProperties = new string[] { };

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            if (p.GetType() == typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>))
            {
                foreach (var blah in //the list)
                {
                    HasPropertyChanged<//TheType>(Type obj1, Type obj2, null);
                }
            }
            object val1 = Original.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(Original, null);
            object val2 = Modified.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(Modified, null);
            if (!IgnoreProperties.Contains(p.Name) && 
                val1 != null && val2 != null && 
                val1.ToString() != val2.ToString())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# implementation of deep/recursive object comparison in .net 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539989/c-sharp-implementation-of-deep-recursive-object-comparison-in-net-3-5)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan how so?  This is an custom implementation, not a copy paste.

Comment: Because, in my opinion, you're asking a question that has ultimately been asked before; and the top answer on that question will solve your problem to boot.  Hey, if nobody else agrees, then it wont be closed - that's democracy :)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan What's happening to this site?  I'm not asking for a dll to solve my problem, I'm asking for some help crafting my code. Thanks for your opinion though...it's super helpful.

Comment: I understand what you're saying; I'm just one user, not the whole site.  My point of view is purely that if there's a library out there, that's open source, and which does exactly what you want and more besides, you might be better off using that.  You're bound to get other answers and I'm sure they'll be more helpful to you than mine.  I've +1d you to help maximise that chance

Comment: @AndrasZoltan I take it all back.  Thanks. ;)

Comment: In addition, @jim, the reason for the inequality is, I believe due to the lack of a defined equality on the items in the collection, hence the references are being compared, but they're not the same reference, even though they might be equal.  You might be better of using .Equals and making sure all your custom types have that method overriden.

Comment: no worries, SO really is the best QA site bar none, despite my being here LOL  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with types at runtime, you should have a non-generic version of your function which takes a `Type` parameter:

```
private bool HasPropertyChanged<T>(T Original, T Modified, string[] IgnoreProperties)
{
    return HasPropertyChanged(typeof(T), Original, Modified, IgnoreProperties);
}

private bool HasPropertyChanged(Type T, object Original, object Modified, string[] IgnoreProperties)
{
    // ...
}
```

With that, you can call the method for the list elements:

```
if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>))
{
    object val1 = p.GetValue(Original, null);
    object val2 = p.GetValue(Modified, null);

    // First check count...
    PropertyInfo countProperty = p.PropertyType.GetProperty("Count");
    int count1 = countProperty.GetValue(val1, null);
    int count2 = countProperty.GetValue(val2, null);
    if (count1 != count2) return true;

    // Now iterate:
    var enumerator1 = (val1 as System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
    var enumerator2 = (val2 as System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator1.MoveNext())
    {
        enumerator2.MoveNext();
        // check for null, skipping here...
        object elem1 = enumerator1.Current;
        object elem2 = enumerator2.Current;
        if (HasPropertyChanged(elem1.GetType(), elem1, elem2, IgnoreProperties)) return true;
    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Carlos?  Why compare the count of properties?  shouldn't they be the same count since they have to be the same type?

Comment: This assumes that the items are in the same order in both lists.  If you can't depend on this, your items would need to implement some kind of identity that can be used to look up the item from the first list in the second (as you can't make a reference comparison, because presumably your instances would be different).

Comment: Not the count of properties; the `Count` property of the two lists - one element may contain a list with [1, 2, 3, 4], and the other with [1, 2, 3]. The enumerator loop assumes that they're both the same, so we need to check the size of the lists before.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to be careful about your usage of == as opposed to Equals(). You are extracting all property values as objects;

```
object val1 = Original.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(Original, null);
object val2 = Modified.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(Modified, null);
```

And then using the equality operator to compare them. For reference types, this operator returns true only if they are the same instance, which in this case, they will never be - because val1 and val2 are 2 distinct objects. You could drop the .ToString() calls and replace with;

```
if (val1.Equals(val2) { ... }
```

This is a more correct approach for what you are trying to do (I assume).

Now for the collections issue - why not try;

```
if (p is IEnumerable)
{
    foreach (object o in p)
    {
        if (!o.HasPropertyChanged(...))
            return false;
    }
}
```

I don't think you need to implement this with generics. The only purpose of the generic type that I can see is to ensure the types passed in are the same. So, just drop that, change T to 'Type' or 'object' and make a comparison for type in the first line of the function;

```
if (Original.GetType() != Modified.GetType())
    return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the refresher on the reference types vs the value types...that was very helpful.  As far as your suggestion on the IEnumerable, p.HasPropertyChanged, doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really finish that thought correctly - see modification to the IEnumerable part.

Comment: @rjlohan, its not quite correct to they they *never* will be equal, if the two objects point to the same reference then they will be equal.