# Comparing two enumrations of PropertyInfo that results from reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have two states of objects that I would like to compare an initial state and final state.I capture all annotated properties of a specific state through reflection, and I would like to compare both states to check whether they are equal ,or not.I have this try but I believe it is inefficient more-ever it doesn't work :D.

```
private static bool areSame(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> initial,IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> final)
    {


        foreach (PropertyInfo initialPropertyInfo in initial)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo finalPropertyInfo in final)
            {
                if (initialPropertyInfo.Name == finalPropertyInfo.Name)
                {
                    if (initialPropertyInfo.GetValue(initialViewModel) != finalPropertyInfo.GetValue(finalViewModel))
                  //  Console.WriteLine(initialPropertyInfo.GetValue(initialViewModel));
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

//final and initial view models are the object from which I extracted the properties,they are Object types.

Comment: can you show what do the view models look like? do they contain primitives or objects?

Comment: View model is defined as:
private static Object initialViewModel=null;
private static Object finalViewModel=null;

I pass the required view models instances by functions with signatures:

 public static void Initilize(SysOptionsViewModel o)
        {
            initialViewModel = o;

Comment: See this, because this is what you're actually doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539989/c-sharp-implementation-of-deep-recursive-object-comparison-in-net-3-5

Comment: Can you explain what you want basically. I think that you are generating more complex problem from the basic one.

Comment: I have an enumeration initial (which contains properties obtained through reflection from the initial view model state) and another final one.
I would like just to check whether initial and final properties contents are identical or not;and return true or false.

Comment: Mohammed, I want to see how SysOptionsViewModel looks like :-)

Comment: public class SysOptionsViewModel :ViewModelBase
{
        private BitmapImage _imageSource;
        [CompanyInfo]
        public BitmapImage ImageSource
        {
            get { return _imageSource; }
            set
            {
                _imageSource = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(() => ImageSource);
            }
        }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare two `Objects` using the `==` (or `!=`) operators you're actually using the `System.Object.Equals()` method, and you almost certainly don't like the implementation, that's why you're saying it doesn't work. Unless the types you're using have overriden this to provide a meaningful compassion, you get the framework provided implementation and that actually tests for identity, not meaningful equality.

If your properties were of simple types that do provide proper equality behavior (`String`, `Int32`, etc) then your code would work. Since it does't, your types do not implement `System.Object.Equals()` in a way you consider meaningful. What you probably want is a form of "deep instance comparison", where the two objects are considered equal if they're the same type and each corresponding field is also equal. Well, you don't get that!

The solution depends on the Types of your properties. If you implemented then consider implementing `Equals()` yourself. If you didn't implement them then you'll need to find an other way.