# Compare 2 objects not references

Tags: c#

I have a method that compares 2 generic objects (and it needs to remain objects as this method is required to be generic).  When I compare the objects with either == or .Equals, I get a false.  However when I type cast the object to my known type at the time, I get true.  My only explanation is that it is comparing the references or pointers, which are not the same, but the objects are.

```
    private static bool AreSame(object a, object b)
    {
        bool equalsResult = a.Equals(b);
        bool compareResult = a == b;
        bool castingResult = (a as MyClass).Equals(b as MyClass);
    }
```

Without knowing pre-compile what classes or objects I will be comparing, how can I go about solving this problem?

Comment: This should only happen if `MyClass.Equals(MyClass)` behaves differently from `MyClass.Equals(object)` which it shouldn't if implemented correctly. You could use generics and add an `IEquatable<T>` constraint if you always want to use the typed version of `Equals`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183759.aspx

Comment: Objects comparison check the references, i.e. addresses. MyClass comparison compares the content depending on MyClass "Equals" implementation (or that of the inherited "Equals").

Comment: check this :http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/compare-2-objects-of-generic-class-type-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: What you're basically asking for is a generic deep object comparison. This question has been duplicated many times on SO. Look at this one for links to solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539989/c-sharp-implementation-of-deep-recursive-object-comparison-in-net-3-5

Comment: @PaulSasik - That's not the same question at all, this is asking why two overloads of `Equals` behave differently and how to choose the correct one.

Comment: Please add the implementations of the `Equals` method(s) in `MyClass`. Does it implement `IEquatable<MyClass>`?

Comment: @Lee: I respectfully disagree. The question is kind of rambling but the last  sentence, the actual question, gets at the heart of the matter which is deep object comparison. Also, this comparison solution needs to work on generic objects meaning the solution is non-trivial and needs more than an interface on an object.

Comment: I should mention what Im trying to do here.  I am putting a tag on a DataGridViewRow, then when the object changes, I want to be able to find that row, and update the data displayed.   Row.Tag is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour can only happen if you have an overload of `Equals` which behaves differently from the `Equals(object)` method inherited from `Object` e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool Equals(MyClass c) { ... }
}
```

in this case you should implement `IEquatable<MyClass>` and override `Object.Equals` to use it:

```
public class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    public bool Equals(MyClass c) { ... }
    public override bool Equals(object o)
    { 
        var c = o as MyClass;
        return c != null && Equals(c);
    }
}
```

then you can use your existing method or a generic one:

```
private static bool AreSame<T>(T a, T b) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I had all of that (except the 'where T : IEquatable<T>' so it wasnt working.  However, when I want to use 'AreSame', the items are already objects.  When passing in objects to 'AreSame', I get the compile error: The type 'object' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method .AreSame<T>(T, T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'object' to 'System.IEquatable<object>'.

Comment: @Tizz - `object` doesn't implement `IEquatable<object>` so no that won't work, however you can still do `a.Equals(b)` or `Object.Equals(a, b)` and it will as long as your overloads of `Equals` all behave consistently.