# Check for identical objects

Tags: c#

How i cant check objects for equality?
I have 2 objects of Class Storage(with List of class products) and i want to find mutual products, but when i check Identical 2 objects of Product, they aren't identical.

```
class Storage
    {
       public List<Product> many_product;
       public Storage(List<Product> el)
        {
            this.many_product.AddRange(el);
        }
        public static Storage mutual_products(Storage a, Storage b)
        {
            Storage mutal_products = new Storage();
            foreach (var prod in a.many_product)
                if (b.many_product.Contains(prod))// return false, but in list is a mutual product
                {
                    mutal_products.many_product.Add(prod);
                }
            return mutal_products;
        }
     }
```

The same when i check identical product with if(prod1==prod2)//return false

Comment: "Identical" means that the two objects are actually a single object, which is something that can be checked with `Object.ReferenceEquals` (or `==` if the operator is not overloaded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your product class should implement `IEquatable<Product>` interface for the `Contains` method to work properly. For example:

```
public class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {
        return Name.Equals(other.Name)
            && Price.Equals(other.Price);
    }
}
```

If you are using .NET 5 & C# 9, you can make your `Product` class a `record`. Then there will be no need to implement `IEquatable<Product>` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to do deep comparison (including all nested properties) of objects: using reflection, serialization and so on.
look answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539989/c-sharp-implementation-of-deep-recursive-object-comparison-in-net-3-5) for details

For my own needs, I wrote my own universal object [comparator](https://github.com/miptleha/cs-obj-compare)